# C++ Boost Compile Error with Simple_ls.cpp - Undefinded Referece to boost::filesystem::path::filename

Tags: c++, windows, boost, mingw

I'm kind of "new" to C/C++. I spent many hours beating my head into the desk trying to get Boost installed and working with MinGW on my Windows 8 64bit computer. In my search for answer, I found [a MinGW compiled with Boost 1.55 libraries](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) in it. After double-clicking on the open_distro_window.bat, the errors had changed to something different. Using the [simple_ls.cpp example from the Boost site](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/example/simple_ls.cpp), I received these errors:

```
> g++ simple_ls.cpp -o simple_ls.exe
C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQLpVCt.o:simple_ls.cpp:(.text+0x1ba): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::filename() const'
C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQLpVCt.o:simple_ls.cpp:(.text+0x23a): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::filename() const'
C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQLpVCt.o:simple_ls.cpp:(.text+0x294): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::filename() const'
C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQLpVCt.o:simple_ls.cpp:(.text+0x4bf): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::filename() const'
c:/mingw-boost/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQLpVCt.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried the first sample, [Boost Getting Started Link Your Program](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library), and I still ran into more errors, but one thing at a time. Is there something I'm missing, is the setup for that MinGW compiled with Boost bad, or is it Windows 8? [This is a link to the errors on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/9062785).

Comment: Your should link with boost_filesystem.

Comment: Do you mean when I issuse `g++ simple_ls.cpp -o simple_ls.exe` I should use a `-l` option? Or would what be similar to putting it in the preprocessor area? I'm not too keen on those kinds of things.

Comment: Yes, `-l library_filename`. If the compiler can't find the lib file, then you should add the path of file to the lib path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use g++ with the `-l library_filename` option. If your boost library isn't in the lib path of system, then use `-L BOOST_LIB_DIR` option, let the compiler look in specified directory for library file.

Comment: Getting somewhere. Now I'm only receiving one error.

`>g++ -l "C:\MinGW-Boost\MinGW\lib\" simple_ls.cpp -o simple_ls.exe
    c:/mingw-boost/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\MinGW-Boost\MinGW\lib" simple_ls.cpp -o simple_ls.exe
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

This is the link to the Environment Variables Setup. https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/9062785#file-boost_system_vars-bat

Comment: The file name(maybe like libboost_filesystem*) of boost_filesystem should be after the `-l` option, not a directory.

Comment: What I ended up doing is using this, and also installing this MinGW compiler with Boost already linked from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html This allowed me to use what you said. I also had to contact the developer and add a few more options. in the end, the argument to compile the program was: `g++ -v -Wall -Wextra simple_ls.cpp -o simple_ls.exe -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system` Hope that helps another person out there.